# Digit sum of multiples of 999

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have checked with Maple: The digit sum of the numbers $999\cdot k$ ($k = 1,...,  100000$; the first $100000$ multiples of $999$) is always one of the numbers $27, 36, 45, 54$. Does this pattern continue? Is it true for all $k$?
It is clear that such a digit sum is divisible by 9, and I have already read that it must be at least 27, but why should it not go beyond 54?

Answer (score 2):

Use bigger numbers. In fact, if we choose $k$ to be numbers of the form $1001001001...$ then we get numbers of the form $999999999..$ so we should be able to get arbitrarily large strings of $9$s

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It seems that I was blind on at least one eye. In fact, it was a stupid question.